# Textile-style for numbered and bullet lists?

Tags: support, markdown

I typed a numbered list which generated them in numerical order. Now I want to **displace** the second point. I must now edit the numbers from the second onwards; change 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 and so on.

```
 1. fields submitted the wrong way (URL parameters vs body) or missing
 2. some characters like `?, /` break stuff in URL parameters
 3. some ...
```

---

Can we change the (default) number-list format to this format:

```
 # fields submitted the wrong way (URL parameters vs body) or missing
 # some characters like `?, /` break stuff in URL parameters
 # some ...
```

And the StackOverflow text preprocessor will figure out the point numbers **automatically**, so the user dont have to edit the numbers himself. This will be more friendly to users making/ editing numbered lists.

---

We can also move bullets to `*` character (I know its a potential conflict) and implement nesting:

Nested ordered lists:

```
#point 1
##point 1.1 
##point 1.2
#point 2
##point 2.1
```

Nesting ordered list into bullet lists:

```
*point 1
# subpoint of point 1
#subpoint of point 1
*point 2
#subpoint of point 1
```

Answer (score 19):

Nested lists already exist (indent the next level with four spaces)

```
 - A
     - B
     - C
         - D
         - E
     - F
     - G
 - H
 - I
```

Gives:

> - A
>
>   - B
>   - C
>
>     - D
>     - E
>   - F
>   - G
> - H
> - I

```
1. A
    1. B
    1. C
        1. D
        1. E
    1. F
1. G
1. H
1. I
```

Gives

> 1. A
>
>    1. B
>    2. C
>
>       1. D
>       2. E
>    3. F
> 2. G
> 3. H
> 4. I

When in doubt, mash the spacebar

Answer (score 7):

To answer your first question, the numbers used for numbered lists don't matter. This

```
1. One
1. Two
1. Three
1. Four
1. Five
```

Gives

1. One
2. Two
3. Three
4. Four
5. Five

Don't believe me? Read the source for this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/06511612-1c2a-4d21-a5fe-6edaec15770d/view-source

---

Using `#` would conflict with headers. Also, one of the main benefit of Markdown is to be extremely readable and intuitive. Having `#` turn into numbers is in my opinion far less intuitive than creating lists from, uh, numbers.